# setState inside a setState component renders the whole component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have a ant design modal which I call using the setState, It calls a separate component which holds a ant design form, which is rendered inside the modal body, this is what the functional component looks like.

```
export default function EditTableCell({ record}) {
const [colorSwatch, setColorSwatch] = React.useState(record.color)
const [colorPalletVisible, setColorPalletVisible] = React.useState(false)


if (record === 'add') {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      description: '',
      notes: '',
    })
  }
    
    return (
         <Form>
          <Form.Item
           label="description"
           name="description"
          >
           <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>


        <Form.Item name="color" noStyle>
          <Avatar
            size={32}
            icon={<FormatPainterFilled />}
            style={{ backgroundColor: colorSwatch }}
            onClick={() => setColorPalletVisible(!colorPalletVisible)}
          />
        </Form.Item>
    )
```

now the problem is whenever I call the setColorPalletVisible, the component is re rendering and the initial form values I put are reappearing, that means when the user enters the form field values, and then make a color selection, it rerenders and they lose the data they are typing. So how to make it component run as expected?

https://ant.design/components/form/

Comment: What is `form.setFieldsValue`? where is `form`?

Comment: https://ant.design/components/form/ So according to the official docs, I use it to set initial form fields value, so whenever the setStateColor function is being called, setFormFields is also being called and I am losing the values the user typed.

Comment: form.setFieldsValue this function call is inside the component function body. It needs to be on an effect instead. Otherwise it will be called everytime your component renders.

Comment: Oh I see, It makes sense lemme try this and will let you know if it works

Comment: It works! I just had to put it inside useEffect and included the relevant dependency array and it now works as expected thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component body shouldn't call anything that may mutate state and call re-render functions.

Each time you call `setState` methods, in this case `setColorPalletVisible` React re-renders your component. However, you have `if` statement here which being executed each time your component `re-renders` aka `setColorPalletVisible` is called.

You need to call `form.setFieldsValue` when `record` variable's value has been changed, thus other mutations shouldn't call this function. This is called `side effect`.

Here you can read about the hook provided by Rect to handle this kind of cases.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

In a nutshell, in order to implement side effects based on some dependencies you should call `useEffect` hook which will execute the code after the dependency array is mutated.

In below code, `form.setFieldsValue` will be called only when `record` value has been changed and equal to `add`. `useEffect` dependency array can be empty, which will call the callback function only after initial render of the component.

```js
export default function EditTableCell({ record}) {
  const [colorSwatch, setColorSwatch] = React.useState(record.color)
  const [colorPalletVisible, setColorPalletVisible] = React.useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (record === 'add') {
      form.setFieldsValue({
        description: '',
        notes: '',
      })
    }
  }, [record])

  return (
     <Form>
        <Form.Item
         label="description"
         name="description"
        >
         <Input placeholder={t.payitemsGroupPage.enterPayitem} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>


      <Form.Item name="color" noStyle>
        <Avatar
          size={32}
          icon={<FormatPainterFilled />}
          style={{ backgroundColor: colorSwatch }}
          onClick={() => setColorPalletVisible(!colorPalletVisible)}
        />
      </Form.Item>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Aren for the precise and clear explanation :)